# Python: How to order a list of float

Tags: python

Having a list of floats:

```
a = [465.12, 405.85714285714278, 407.4285714285715, 408.0, 408.1874999999996, 409.875, 411.0, 411.75000000000063, 413.43749999999972, 414.0, 414.66666666666652, 416.33333333333201, 418.0, 417.33333333333252, 419.666666666666, 420.0, 420.74999999999966, 422.70000000000067, 423.0, 423.35714285714295, 425.49999999999994, 426.0, 426.37500000000011, 428.02499999999992, 429.0, 430.03125000000006, 431.8125, 432.0, 432.1874999999996, 434.0625000000004, 435.0, 435.32432432432432, 437.43243243243262, 438.0, 438.39999999999992, 440.40000000000009, 441.0, 441.32432432432427, 442.9459459459456, 444.0, 444.42857142857122, 445.97142857142865, 447.0, 447.92857142857116, 450.0, 450.0, 450.60000000000002, 452.72727272727263, 453.0, 453.19148936170194, 454.78723404255322, 456.0, 456.5, 458.5, 459.0, 459.44999999999959, 461.40000000000015, 462.0, 462.50000000000023, 464.16666666666725]
```

I am trying to sort that list by descendant values (notice I need `ind` because later I will be sorting other lists, such as `sorted_b`, with it):

```
ind = sorted(range(len(a)), key = lambda i:a[i], reverse = True)

sorted_a = [x for (i, x) in sorted(zip(ind, a))]

# sorted_b = [x for (i, x) in sorted(zip(ind, b))]
```

But the code does not work as I would expect:

```
>>> sorted_a
[465.12, 464.16666666666725, 462.5000000000002, 462.0, 461.40000000000015, 459.4499999999996, 459.0, 458.5, 456.5, 456.0, 454.7872340425532, 453.19148936170194, 452.72727272727263, 453.0, 450.6, 450.0, 450.0, 447.92857142857116, 447.0, 445.97142857142865, 444.4285714285712, 444.0, 442.9459459459456, 441.32432432432427, 441.0, 440.4000000000001, 438.3999999999999, 438.0, 437.4324324324326, 435.3243243243243, 435.0, 434.0625000000004, 432.1874999999996, 432.0, 431.8125, 430.03125000000006, 429.0, 428.0249999999999, 426.3750000000001, 426.0, 425.49999999999994, 423.35714285714295, 423.0, 422.70000000000067, 420.0, 420.74999999999966, 419.666666666666, 417.3333333333325, 418.0, 416.333333333332, 414.6666666666665, 414.0, 413.4374999999997, 411.7500000000006, 411.0, 409.875, 408.1874999999996, 408.0, 407.4285714285715, 405.8571428571428]
```

Some values are not correctly sorted as we can easily see in the figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
mpl.plot(sorted_a)
mpl.show()
```

[image: Bad sorting]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need to sort several lists, you are better off using `numpy.argsort`.

Comment: Why not add the newly/incorrectly sorted list to your question for comparison?

Comment: @James Hunt: added, thought it was easier to just see the plot. :-)

Comment: `zip(ind,a)` doesn't make much sense; see: `[a[i]==x for (i,x) in zip(ind,a)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(zip(ind, a))
```

does a lexicographic sort on the `(index, value)` pairs coming from `zip`; since the integer indices are all unique by construction, the sort never even looks at the values and just sorts the indices. What you meant is just

```
[a[i] for i in ind]
```

or better, if NumPy is an option:

```
a = np.array(a)
ind = np.argsort(a)
sorted_a = a[ind]
```

Answer (score 2):

First you form the sort order correctly:

```
ind = sorted(range(len(a)), key = lambda i:a[i], reverse = True)
```

But then if you want to have sorted `a`, you get it as easily as:

```
[ a[i] for i in ind ]
```

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Upvoted. Will accept larsmans' answer though, as he/she explains also what I was doing wrong using sorted(zip(ind, a)). I wish I could accept both, as you answered first! ;-)

Comment: @Peque: It is the right thing to accept larsman's answer instead of mine. It contains all information in my answer plus some more. Acceptance should be based on the quality of answers, not on how fast they are.